# Mapping API response - does not return and dispatch subsequent api calls

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, react-redux, axios

This is my action creator call - having issues - I am getting data from first api call, but when I map through and try to make few more calls(3 in this case) It does not reach till return where it calls the next set of calls - what's the issue here with my code?

```
 export function getData() {
      return async function getData(dispatch) {
        const { data } = await getDataAPI();
        dispatch({ type: GET_DATA, payload: data });
        Object.keys(data).map(async (keyName, keyIndex) => {
          const ENDPOINT = 'build the url with keyName';
          getSingleDATA(ENDPOINT);
        });
      };
    }

    async function getDataAPI() {
      const endpoint = 'url';
      return Request.get(endpoint);
    }

    async function getSingleDATA(ENDPOINT) {
      //CODE DOES NOT GO TO THE LINE BELOW
      return function dispatchgetSingleDATA(dispatch) {
        Request.get(ENDPOINT).then((response) => {
          dispatch({ type: GET_SINGLEDATA + keyIndex, payload: response });
        });
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getSingleDATA()` function is curried, and you're not calling the returned function (which is expecting you to pass it `dispatch`). I think it should read like this:

```
...
Object.keys(data).map(async (keyName, keyIndex) => {
  const ENDPOINT = 'build the url with keyName';
  getSingleDATA(ENDPOINT)(dispatch);
});
```

Secondly, do you even need to curry it? It looks to me like you can rewrite your `getSingleDATA()` function to look like this:

```
async function getSingleDATA(ENDPOINT, dispatch) {
  return Request.get(ENDPOINT).then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_SINGLEDATA + keyIndex, payload: response });
  });
}
```

...and then pass in `dispatch` as a second argument from above (also it looks like `getSingleDATA()` expects to use `keyIndex`, so better pass that in too):

```
getSingleDATA(ENDPOINT, dispatch);  //don't forget keyIndex (not shown)
```

Hopefully that helps. Good luck with it!